# Added IConfiguration service at startup is breaking docker container ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

After adding reCaptcha validation to a contact form on my site my docker container doesnt seem to run the application, though it runs fine deployed with IIS.

After a little debugging I found that adding an IConfiguration Service for accessing appsettings.json contents is breaking the docker container

It seems this service in my startup.cs is the culprit

```
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
                .Build());
```

If I remove the service from startup the application runs in docker but without proper validation as it cannot access the keys in appsettings.

I assume that it is the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() call that is the issue as the environment is different but I am at a loss for how to address the issue.

Here is my dockerfile, its just the standard template.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PortfolioCore/PortfolioCore.csproj", "PortfolioCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PortfolioCore/PortfolioCore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PortfolioCore"
RUN dotnet build "PortfolioCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PortfolioCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PortfolioCore.dll"]
```

Comment: Breaking in what way? Is there an exception?

Comment: AddJsonFile defaults to non-optional. My guess is that your file is not where it's expected to be, perhaps with docker file paths being different from local use (ie if using Linux containers). Assuming your file is in the project have you verified its getting copied on publish? Particularly inside the container itself. You can shell in and look at the files. I think you can omit SetBasePath as the infrastructure should have a sensible default (assuming you're using HostBuilder) Directory.GetCurrentDirectory may not be correct